# Splitting a character column by pattern matching

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, grepl

```
                                       Province                   ElecDistName                               Candidate Votes Majority  Vper MajPer
                                          <chr>                          <chr>                                   <chr> <int>    <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Newfoundland and Labrador/Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador St. John's East/St. John's-Est                     Nick Whalen Liberal 20974      646  46.7    1.4
2 Newfoundland and Labrador/Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador St. John's East/St. John's-Est Jack Harris ** NDP-New Democratic Party 20328       NA  45.3     NA
3 Newfoundland and Labrador/Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador St. John's East/St. John's-Est           Deanne Stapleton Conservative  2938       NA   6.5     NA
4 Newfoundland and Labrador/Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador St. John's East/St. John's-Est        David Anthony Peters Green Party   500       NA   1.1     NA
5 Newfoundland and Labrador/Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador St. John's East/St. John's-Est                   Sean Burton Communist   140       NA   0.3     NA
6                   New Brunswick/Nouveau-Brunswick                    Fundy Royal                 Alaina Lockhart Liberal 19136     1775  40.9    3.8
```

[Top of Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYFFb.jpg)

Amateur question here, I'm trying to split the Candidate column into two, one containing the name, the other containing the party. I've tried some of the separate functions posted on here:

```
separate(ElecResults, Candidate, into = c("Name", "Party"), sep = " (?=[^ ]+$)")
```

But this seems to miss a lot of observations. For the Candidates with three names, the problem is obvious, but there are others that it just seems to miss entirely (the candidates with the inexplicable double asterisks for one).

I have tried to think of if functions combined with grepl where it would identify the most common party names, such as Liberal, Conservative, NDP and Green, and create a new column called Party with the party name in it, but continuously get error messages everytime I try.

If anyone has an idea for how I can split this column it would be a huge help.

Thank you!

Here is the code using dput:

```
structure(list(Province = c("Newfoundland and Labrador/Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", 
"Newfoundland and Labrador/Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", "Newfoundland and Labrador/Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", 
"Newfoundland and Labrador/Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", "Newfoundland and Labrador/Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", 
"New Brunswick/Nouveau-Brunswick"), ElecDistName = c("St. John's East/St. John's-Est", 
"St. John's East/St. John's-Est", "St. John's East/St. John's-Est", 
"St. John's East/St. John's-Est", "St. John's East/St. John's-Est", 
"Fundy Royal"), Candidate = c("Nick Whalen Liberal", "Jack Harris ** NDP-New Democratic Party", 
"Deanne Stapleton Conservative", "David Anthony Peters Green Party", 
"Sean Burton Communist", "Alaina Lockhart Liberal"), Votes = c(20974L, 
20328L, 2938L, 500L, 140L, 19136L), Majority = c(646L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1775L), Vper = c(46.7, 45.3, 6.5, 1.1, 0.3, 40.9), MajPer = c(1.4, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.8)), .Names = c("Province", "ElecDistName", 
"Candidate", "Votes", "Majority", "Vper", "MajPer"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Difficult to help without seeing what your data object looks like.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've posted the code now

Comment: how many different parties do you have? And are they named uniformly (e.g. Conservative is always Conservative)

Comment: A better way to share the data so that people can load it into R is using`dput ()`, like this: `dput(head(ElecResults))`

Comment: Thanks, I've added that now

Comment: There are 5 main parties, and they are uniform, though there are some fringe parties that might be scattered through there - I'm not overly concerned if these fringe parties show up as NAs if that makes things easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach using the `fuzzyjoin` package

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

parties <- data_frame(party = c("Liberal", "NDP-New Democratic Party", "Conservative", "Green Party", "Communist"))

df %>% 
  regex_left_join(parties, by = c(Candidate = "party")) %>% 
  replace_na(list(party = "minor")) %>%
  mutate(Candidate = str_replace(Candidate, party, "")) %>%
  select(Candidate, party)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>               Candidate                    party
#>                   <chr>                    <chr>
#> 1          Nick Whalen                   Liberal
#> 2       Jack Harris **  NDP-New Democratic Party
#> 3     Deanne Stapleton              Conservative
#> 4 David Anthony Peters               Green Party
#> 5          Sean Burton                 Communist
#> 6      Alaina Lockhart                   Liberal
```

Note that the last select was only added to illustrate that the method works. I like this approach in particular because other parties that might show up in the dataframe can be nicely taken care of using `replace_na`

Answer (score 0):

Here is some basic code, which you'll need to mod. Put each party name inside the quotes separated by a |

```
require(dplyr)
require(stringr)

df <- data.frame(Candidate = "Nick Whalen Liberal", Majority = 1)
parties <- c("Liberal|Conservative")
df %>% mutate(Name = str_sub(Candidate, 1, str_locate(Candidate, parties)[1] - 1))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll play around with this